# Everything detects+connects to everything including Home Laptop and Home WIFI except Home Laptop to Home WIFI

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

**SOLVED**:

- **Home WIFI** is set to **Channel 4** and has over **90% signal**.
- **Neighbour WIFI** is set to **Channel 4** and has over **90% signal**.
- I set **Home WIFI** to **Channel 1** - it was set to **Auto**
- **Home Laptop** detects **Home WIFI** 5 times after I switch Router off and on - it used to not detect after 1-2 switches.
- **Home Laptop** connects to **Home WIFI** in less than 2 seconds - it used to take more than 10 seconds.

---

***Problem***:

- **Home Laptop** doesn't detect **Home WIFI** except sometimes

***Exception***:

- Sometimes **Home Laptop** detects and connects to **Home WIFI**
  successfully + internet works great like when I posted this question. Generally it happens after
  turning **Home Router** off and on.

***Mission***:

- To make **Home Laptop** detect **Home WIFI**

---

***WIFI detection***:

- Everything detects **Home WIFI** except **Home Laptop**
- **Home Laptop** detects **Every WIFI** except **Home WIFI**
- **Home Laptop** detects **Home WIFI** on **Neighbour Cable Line**
- **Home Laptop** doesn't detect **Neighbour WIFI** on **Home Cable Line**

***Info***:

- **OS**: Windows 10 Home 64bit
- **Router**: Nokia G-140w-G
- **WIFI Adapter**: Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4A Wireless Network Adapter

***Tried***:

- **Windows Update** - up to date: 24.11.2019
- **Windows Reset** including deleting files
- **Network Reset** + **Windows Restart**
- **Router Reset**
- **Router Unplug** everything for more than a minute
- **WIFI Adapter Driver Update** - "Windows has determined that the best
  driver for this device is already installed"
- **WIFI Adapter Drivers Replacement** - 3 replaced
- **WIFI Adapter** enable/disable
- **Mobile Hot Spot** - doesn't detect

Comment: Is your WiFi network 2.4 GHz or 5 GHz?

Comment: @MrEthernet 2.4Ghz

Comment: Can you clarify what this means? "*Laptop detects Home WIFI on Neighbour Cable Line. Laptop doesn't detect Neighbour WIFI on Home Cable Line*." So did you temporarily swap your router with your neighbor for testing purposes? This description is somewhat ambiguous and hard to follow.

Comment: @MrEthernet Yes, I swap 2 routers to 2 different cable lines in 10 minutes total. I lost by 0:2 score.

Comment: @MrEthernet, I added possible reason, check out.

Comment: If you changed the password for Home WiFi since you originally connected Home Laptop to it, perhaps you just need to choose "Forget" on the laptop and then connect to Home WiFi again using the new password.

Comment: @MrEthernet I am sorry, but I was wrong. A new morning and it doesn't detect again. I plan to try Mobile Hotspot again or buy a USB WIFI Adapter.

Comment: @MrEthernet I found the solution, check out the answer and question edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why Home Laptop doesn't detect **Home WIFI** in a stable way is **Home WIFI Channel** overlaps with **Neighbour WIFI Channel**.

To solve the problem, set **Home WIFI Channel** to different value.

Read more:

[Why channel 1, 6 and 11 are best for Wifi communication 802.11n?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18904/why-channel-1-6-and-11-are-best-for-wifi-communication-802-11n)

[Why use wifi channels other than 1, 6 or 11?](https://superuser.com/questions/382042/why-use-wifi-channels-other-than-1-6-or-11)

[Should WiFi routers be set to a channel or choose automatically?](https://superuser.com/questions/1308736/should-wifi-routers-be-set-to-a-channel-or-choose-automatically/1308847)

Comment: Your solution solved my problem! Great!

Comment: Thanks for the update!

Comment: What is the easiest way to solve this? I can't able to understand answers because it's too technical

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your list of environment tests (first paragraph), do the following two steps:

1. Update the Router firmware and then do a hard reset of the router.
2. Try a different router (borrow one if you can).